# Recepção de Dados e Conversão para String

Tags: c#, string, conversão

```
byte[] ret = new byte[29];
s.Receive(ret); 

Console.WriteLine("Retorno de Dados" +
    (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret).Replace("211","")));

string tex = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret).Replace("211 ", "");
switch (tex)
{
    case "007F": Console.WriteLine("Situação 1"); break;
}
Console.Readkey();
```

A variável tex que eu acredito já ter transferido para string, não é idêntica a declaração literal no case, qual tratamento devo dar a mesma para que quando comparadas o resultado seja que elas são idênticas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu texto provavelmente tem mais caracteres vazios no final (provavelmente `'\0'`), então quando você imprime parece que o valor é somente "007F", mas na verdade ele tem vários caracteres `'\u0000'`, o que faz com que as strings sejam diferentes. Se você `Trim` estes caracteres do final, você deve conseguir a sua comparação correta, como mostra o exemplo abaixo.

```
byte[] b = new byte[29];
var bi = 0;
b[bi++] = (byte)'2';
b[bi++] = (byte)'1';
b[bi++] = (byte)'1';

b[bi++] = (byte)'0';
b[bi++] = (byte)'0';
b[bi++] = (byte)'7';
b[bi++] = (byte)'F';

var tex = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
Console.WriteLine("Retorno de Dados: " + tex);
Console.WriteLine("Retorno de Dados: <<" + tex + ">>"); // mostra os outros caracteres

Console.WriteLine(tex.Replace("211", "") == "007F"); // false, o primeiro string tem mais caracteres
Console.WriteLine(tex.Replace("211", "").Replace("\0", "") == "007F");
```

Uma outra alternativa é usar somente o número de bytes que foram recebidos na chamada a `s.Receive` quando converter os bytes para strings:

```
byte[] ret = new byte[29];
int bytesRecvd = s.Receive(ret); 

Console.WriteLine("Retorno de Dados" +
    (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret, 0, bytesRecvd).Replace("211","")));

string tex = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret, 0, bytesRecvd).Replace("211 ", "");
switch (tex)
{
    case "007F": Console.WriteLine("Situação 1"); break;
}
Console.Readkey();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente.